# AOSP: Non-focusable but LongClickable TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-source, android-framework

I just downloaded AOSP and modified TextView for my purpose.

I have added a LongClick Listener to the TextView, which shows a simple Toast.

Since I modified the Android framework, it is reflected into all the apps and entire Android OS.

I have now run into a weird issue where the TextView is getting focus in some places and other underlying widgets are not getting any focus. This is creating lot of issues.

For eg: In Settings app, The 'Wi-Fi' text is receiving focus, but I cannot enter the wi-fi settings unless I click in any empty area in the Wi-Fi list item.
(I hope am clear!)

Another example: I am unable to select the Radio Button just because the text corresponding to Radio Button receives focus.

So my question is:

1. Is there any way I can make TextView non-focusable but receive Long Click events?
2. Is there any way I can pass the focus down to the parent layout?
3. Any other way you can suggest?

(PS: Please do not say what I am doing is right or wrong. It's just a feasibility test for what I am trying to achieve.)

Answer (score 0):

A view does have the attributes "focusable" and "longClickable". Have you tried a combination of these?

Comment: Yes. I have tried it. But no luck. TextView remains focusable.

Comment: Got interested and did some testing myself. Have to admit, there don't seem to be any dead simple solutions to this.

Comment: Thanks Gelupa. Hope someone here can help :)